# Creating relationships between dependent variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, factor-analysis

I have data on a $M$ systems (say different material alloys). Each system (material) has $N$ variables (properties). I would like to correlate one variable(say material strength) of the system with a small sub-set of the variables $N_S$ (such as composition, crystal-structure etc.).

I'm not sure which analysis is more appropriate for this scenario. Do I need to use

- factor analysis -- which I believe treats all variables as dependent
  variables or
- multiple regression -- which treats one variable as dependent and others as independent variable.

Just to clarify, the variable values are not continuous i.e., for given value/range of variables, a system/systems may or may not exist.

Comment: why not just do a correlation matrix?

Comment: I have no background in statistics.  I read a little bit online and I just posted a question based on what I learnt

Comment: In that case, start with a correlation matrix, and do a graphic, too, not just numbers. It is available in most stat packages. That is good, standard exploratory practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting out with a data analysis, it is good practice to "look" at the data, which means poring over graphs of distributions, descriptive statistics (frequencies, proportions, means, ranges, etc), and try to get a feel for the data, without doing analysis that answers specific questions.  In this case I would recommend building correlation matrices, both graphically and numerically.
This will give you a sense of how the variables are related to each other, and will suggest what method(s) might be best to proceed.

Comment: Thank you. Correlation matrix definitely looks like a good place to start